# Selenium IE выдает ошбику NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer

Как исправись ошибку?

Текущий код:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Ie
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="D:\projects\camera_downloader\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver = Ie(service=service)

driver.get("https://google.com")

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "html") # <- здесь ошибка
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\camera_downloader\main.py", line 156, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\projects\camera_downloader\main.py", line 42, in main
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "html")
  File "C:\Users\thede\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1153, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\thede\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 400, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\thede\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 236, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with css selector == html
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Вы не верите ошибке?

Comment: Очень остроумно... Мне казалось, что это очевидно если есть ошибка, то ее нужно исправить

Comment: Допустим, такого элемента нет. Какие пути исправления вы в этом случае видите?

Answer (score 0):

Я так полагаю, вы пытаетесь вернуть содержимое всей страницы.

`By.CSS_SELECTOR` ищет элемент по названию селектора из таблицы стиля css

Для того чтобы найти элемент по названию тэга html используйте `By.tagName`.

В вашем случае лучше использовать выражение:

```py
driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));
```

Comment: Для того чтобы получить содержимое страницы я могу использовать driver.page_source. Проблема не только с By.CSS_SELECTOR, а и с другими методами поиска эллементов. Если я ищу эллемент через js с помощью document.querySelector("html"), то все отлично и эллемент находиться

Comment: А при чем тут js? Это два разных языка. В данном случае вы не можете использовать поиск селектора, даже если html указан в таблице стилей. Если ошибка заключается не в этом, то в чем смысл вопроса?

Comment: Ваш ответ не решил ошибку, я привел пример с js чтоб показать что метод нахождения эллемента не имеет значения и ошибка не в этом....

Answer (score 0):

если у Вас селектор с названием 'html', тогда ошибка здесь

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#html")
```

если это не селектор читайте внимательно документацию https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html